# Is it safe to create symlink under /var/www/ which points to my home directory?

Tags: web-server, apache-2.4, sudo

I am using local Ubuntu server with Apache 2.4. I am running as a default user Ubuntu and each time I need to change something under `/var/www/` I have to use *sudo* to avoid permission denied messages.

I have thought an alternative to create a directory under my `home`, say `public_html` which will contain all documents and then create a *symlink* under `/var/www/` which points to `public_html`

Is it safe to point Apache to my home directory? Can you guys recommend any other idea to avoid repeated use of *sudo*?

Comment: Symlinks are a bad idea, on if your user is used for other stuff as well, such as receiving mail, changing a DocumentRoot for your website to your home directory, or a subdirectory therein, is not ideal either.